# React Stateful Components without classes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming

In React, we can write components as pure functions. However, the problem with this is that you can't use it as stateful components because of the lack of lifecycle hooks and state. So, I wonder if is there any way to create stateful components without using classes.

Something that I found is the `createClass` helper. But, React has moved this helper into their own package in the release `15.5.0`, [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-class). Also, they recommend that you migrate them to JavaScript classes because classes are now the preferred way to create components in React. Therefore, I don't think that using this helper could be a good idea.

On the other hand, Facebook recommends the use of High Order Components (HOCs) which is an advanced technique in React for reusing component logic. HOCs are not part of the React API, per se. They are a pattern that emerges from React's compositional nature. But, I couldn't find a way to create common stateful components without classes.

Has anyone gone through this? Is there any way to use React as a some purely functional solution?

Comment: With *monad*'s.

Comment: Do you have experience with any functional programming languages? You can simulate stateful operations using pure functions, you just need to return the new state as one of the return values, and then use that state as one of the parameters to the next time you call the function. The abstraction for this is called the "State monad".

Comment: yes but what about react lifecycle hooks?

Comment: You can use lenses or cursors. This represents a `{ get, set }` pair of functions that can read and replace some subset of centralized state. One example of a library to help you implement this is http://omniscientjs.github.io/

Comment: Nice, didn't know about that. Btw, that library uses the `createClass` helper also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Writing Stateful component without using classes is definitely a choice made by several developers. I recommend to use 'recompose' which has nice and easy implementation to write stateful components without class, yet apply state, both local and from store. Here is an example:

```
import compose from 'recompose/compose'
import withState from 'recompose/withState'
import withProps from 'recompose/withProps'

Pure.js

function MyComponent(props) ({

  local: { prop1, prop2 },
  setProp1 
})

  return <div>{prop1}</div>
}

const defaultState = {
  prop1: false,
  prop2: false
}

const enhance = compose(
  withState('local', 'updateLocal', defaultState),
  withProps(({ local: { prop1, prop2 }, updateLocal }) => ({
    setProp1: (newValue) => updateLocal(state => ({...state, prop1: newValue }))
  })))

export default enhance(MyComponent)
```

Comment: Where has this library been all my life.

Comment: Thanks! what about react lifecycle hooks? Can you use it?

Comment: @mattias, I am not sure that lifecycle events can be attached too. So far I haven't seen that implemented. You might want to visit [recompose](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose) library for more details.

Answer (score 10):

React supports this since version 16.8. From the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html):

> Hooks are a new addition in React 16.8. They let you use state and other React features without writing a class.

A simple example:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

function Example() {
  // Declare a new state variable, which we'll call "count"
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

For an example of how to use lifecycles, check out [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Comment: It's not experimental anymore so you might want to update your answer

Comment: Note that React `16.8` is out and has *hooks* support

Comment: You'll have to update it again in a year, removing the word "new" ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [react-instance](https://github.com/pravdomil/react-instance#readme) can become handy. Take a look at examples below.

**Save state in local variable:**

```
import React from "react"
import instance from "react-instance"

const App = instance(({ forceUpdate }) => {
  let time = 0

  const timer = setInterval(() => {
    time++
    forceUpdate()
  }, 100)

  return {
    render() {
      return time
    },
    unmount() {
      clearInterval(timer)
    },
  }
})
```

**Save state in component state:**

```
import React from "react"
import instance from "react-instance"

const App = instance(instance => {
  instance.state = { time: 0 }

  const timer = setInterval(() => {
    instance.setState({ time: instance.state.time + 1 })
  }, 100)

  return {
    render() {
      return instance.state.time
    },
    unmount() {
      clearInterval(timer)
    },
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create a simple stateful component named Comp without the usage of es6 classes.

[Here is the code](https://codesandbox.io/s/pww84m1v70)

Basically I'm linking the prototype of the Comp function (our stateful component) to the prototype object of React.Component and I pass down to it Comp's props to initialize it properly. After that you can use every function of the React.Component object on the Comp.prototype. I used some just an example. I don't know if this is the best way in the "most javascript" way to use react